# Does Tagetes Filifolia transplant well into an indoor window box for the winter?

Tags: herbs, transplanting

I have 4 [Tagetes Filifolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagetes_filifolia) plants from my community garden, and it smells pleasant enough to keep indoors for a Minnesota winter. Will it transplant well, since it's not likely going to flower before winter?

How do I transplant it? The same way as any other normal plant?

Comment: Annuals don't usually transplant well. Any disturbance, and they usually just "flower and die", which is all they need to do to reproduce themselves naturally. If you want to grow annuals in pots, then sow the seed in pots - you can put the pots outside for a while if you want.

Comment: I've seen sunchokes recover.